# Use result of a Hive/Impala query inside another query

Tags: hive, impala, hue

I'm working with hive/impala and I often run into the need of having to query the results of a `show partition` to get specific partition. Let's suppose I have a table `tbl1` partitioned by fields `country` and `date`. So, `show partitions tbl1` would result in something like this

```
country=c1/date=d1
country=c1/date=d3
country=c2/date=d2
```

I want to do something like `select * from (show partitions tbl1) a where a.country='c1'` and I want to do this in Hue or shell (hive and impala).
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone ever finds this useful, this is what I ended up doing. Assuming you have `spark-shell` or `spark2-shell`, you can store the output of `show partitions` in a dataframe and then transform such dataframe. This is what I did (inside `spark2-shell`:

```
val df = spark.sql("show partitions tbl1").map(row => {
    val arrayValues = row.getString(0).split("/")
    (arrayValues.head.split("=")(1), arrayValues(1).split("=")(1))
}).toDF("country", "date")
```

this takes the list of partitions (a DataFrame[String]) and splits the dataframe by `/` and then for each piece, splits for `=` and takes the value

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are trying is possible inside impala/hive directly.

I can suggest an alternative way:

Use bash in combination impala/hive
so instead of entering into interactive modes in hive and impala , use the command line option to pass the query from bash shell itself so that the result comes back to bash shell and then use grep or other text processing commands to process it.

so it would seem like

```
impala -k -i <> --ssl -ca_cert <> -B -q "show partitions tbl1" | grep "country=c1"
```

here u need to put required values in place of <>

so in this way you can use grep/sed or other tools to get the desired output.
Obviously it depends on your use case what you exactly want..but I hope this can help

Comment: also u need to put <db_name>.tbl1 in mentioned query

Comment: I've been using a similar method with `hive` or `impala-shell` with `bash`, but more times than I'd like to, I have to use `hue` so I was looking for a method that would be valid for both environments. Thank you